# Soft creation and soft delete on SQL table

Tags: sql

I have the following table scheme for a blog post:

```
create table dbo.Post ( 
  Id int not null
    constraint PK_Post_Id primary key clustered (Id),
  Created datetime null,    
  Content nvarchar (max) not null,
  Deleted datetime null,
  Summary nvarchar (4000) not null,
  Title nvarchar (400) not null
)
```

In this case I am using Created and Deleted for soft Create / Delete.

So if Created is null then the post is not published yet ... If Delete is not null then the post was soft deleted. Then I frequently check which posts were deleted more than 10 days ago and permanently delete them.

I am not sure about the Created part ... Maybe I should also have an Updated field on this ... So Created would be not null after the first creation and then I would use Updated for soft creation? Not sure there ...

Can I get some advice on this?

Comment: How about: "created", **"published"** and "deleted"

Comment: Yes, that is an option to. It makes sense ...

Comment: which server are you using (eg SQL Server, MySQL, PGSQL)?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2014